# Converting a block of multiple inline comments into a single line with regex

Tags: regex

I'm trying to convert a library of functions into using JSDocs and I'm having an issue with converting the first instance of a multi line comment block into a single line @description

In the example I am trying to make a regex that will turn the 3'rd and 4'th lines into the following without modifying the other blocks of comments.

`///@description Returns a string formatted according to the given format string using the given date-time value or current local time if no date-time is given.`

I've been playing around for a while and have been able to select the first block of code but haven't been able to get new lines working to only select the first occurrence.

***Example function***

```
date_format

//  Returns a string formatted according to the given format string using
//  the given date-time value or current local time if no date-time is given.

//      format      string controlling date formatting, string
//      datetime    date-time value, real (optional)

//  Day format characters:
//      d - day of the month with leading zeros, 2 digits with leading zeros; 01 through 31
//      D - day of the week, textual, 3 letters; Fri
//      j - day of the month without leading zeros; 1 through 31
//      l - day of the week, textual, long; Friday
//      N - ISO 8601 day number of the week; 1 (Monday) through 7 (Sunday)
//      S - English ordinal suffix, textual, 2 characters; st, nd, rd, th
//      w - day of the week, numeric, 0 (Sunday) through 6 (Saturday)
//      z - day of the year (starting from zero); 0 through 365

//  Week format characters:
//      W - ISO 8601 week number of year, weeks starting on Monday; 42

//  Month format characters:
//      F - month, textual, long; January
//      m - month with leading zeros; 01 through 12
//      M - month, textual, 3 letters; Jan
//      n - month without leading zeros; 1 through 12
//      t - number of days in the given month; 28 through 31

//  Year format characters:
//      L - whether it is a leap year; 0 or 1
//      o - ISO 8601 year, like Y unless ISO week belongs to prev or next year; 2008
//      Y - year, 4 digits; 1999
//      y - year, 2 digits; 99

//  Time format characters:
//      a - lowercase Ante meridiem and Post meridiem; am or pm
//      A - uppercase Ante meridiem and Post meridiem; AM or PM
//      g - hour, 12-hour format without leading zeros; 1 through 12
//      G - hour, 24-hour format without leading zeros; 0 through 23
//      h - hour, 12-hour format; 01 through 12
//      H - hour, 24-hour format; 00 through 23
//      i - minutes, with leading zero; 00 through 59
//      s - seconds, with leading zero; 00 through 59

//  Full Date/Time format characters:
//      c - ISO 8601 extended format date; 2004-02-12T15:19:21
//      r - RFC 2822 formatted data; Thu, 21 Dec 2000 16:01:07 -0000
//      U - seconds since the Unix epoch
//
//      \ - following character should be returned literally, not interpreted

//  Examples:
//      date_format("l jS of F Y h:i:s A") == "Sunday 4th of May 2008 05:45:34 PM"
//      date_format('\I\t \i\s \t\h\e zS \d\a\y.') == "It is the 124th day."

/// GMLscripts.com/license
{
    var str,dat,out,day,month,year,week,weekday,second,minute,hour24,hour12,i,c;
    str = argument[0];
    if (argument_count > 1) dat = argument[1];
    else dat = date_current_datetime();
    out = "";
    day     = date_get_day(dat);
    month   = date_get_month(dat);
    year    = date_get_year(dat);
    week    = date_get_week(dat);
    weekday = date_get_weekday(dat);
    second  = date_get_second(dat);
    minute  = date_get_minute(dat);
    hour24  = date_get_hour(dat);
    hour12  = ((hour24+23) mod 12)+1;
    for (i=1; i<=string_length(str); i+=1) {
        c = string_char_at(str,i);
        switch (c) {
        case "F":
            switch (month) {
            case 1:  out += "January";   break;
            case 2:  out += "February";  break;
            case 3:  out += "March";     break;
            case 4:  out += "April";     break;
            case 5:  out += "May";       break;
            case 6:  out += "June";      break;
            case 7:  out += "July";      break;
            case 8:  out += "August";    break;
            case 9:  out += "September"; break;
            case 10: out += "October";   break;
            case 11: out += "November";  break;
            case 12: out += "December";  break;
            }
            break;
        case "M":
            switch (month) {
            case 1:  out += "Jan"; break;
            case 2:  out += "Feb"; break;
            case 3:  out += "Mar"; break;
            case 4:  out += "Apr"; break;
            case 5:  out += "May"; break;
            case 6:  out += "Jun"; break;
            case 7:  out += "Jul"; break;
            case 8:  out += "Aug"; break;
            case 9:  out += "Sep"; break;
            case 10: out += "Oct"; break;
            case 11: out += "Nov"; break;
            case 12: out += "Dec"; break;
            }
            break;
        case "l":
            switch (weekday) {
            case 0: out += "Sunday";    break;
            case 1: out += "Monday";    break;
            case 2: out += "Tuesday";   break;
            case 3: out += "Wednesday"; break;
            case 4: out += "Thursday";  break;
            case 5: out += "Friday";    break;
            case 6: out += "Saturday";  break;
            }
            break;
        case "D":
            switch (weekday) {
            case 0: out += "Sun"; break;
            case 1: out += "Mon"; break;
            case 2: out += "Tue"; break;
            case 3: out += "Wed"; break;
            case 4: out += "Thu"; break;
            case 5: out += "Fri"; break;
            case 6: out += "Sat"; break;
            }
            break;
        case "S":
            if (day >= 10 && day <= 20) out += "th";
            else if ((day mod 10) == 1) out += "st";
            else if ((day mod 10) == 2) out += "nd";
            else if ((day mod 10) == 3) out += "rd";
            else                        out += "th";
            break;
        case "o":
            if (month ==  1 && day <=  3 && week != 1) { out += string(year-1); break; }
            if (month == 12 && day >= 29 && week == 1) { out += string(year+1); break; }
        case "Y": out += string(year); break;
        case "y": out += string_copy(string(year),3,2); break;
        case "m": if (month < 10) out += "0";
        case "n": out += string(month); break;
        case "d": if (day < 10) out += "0";
        case "j": out += string(day); break;
        case "H": if (hour24 < 10) out += "0";
        case "G": out += string(hour24); break;
        case "h": if (hour12 < 10) out += "0";
        case "g": out += string(hour12); break;
        case "i": if (minute < 10) out += "0"; out += string(minute); break;
        case "s": if (second < 10) out += "0"; out += string(second); break;
        case "a": if (hour24 < 12) out += "am" else out += "pm"; break;
        case "A": if (hour24 < 12) out += "AM" else out += "PM"; break;
        case "U": out += string(round(date_second_span(dat,25569))); break;
        case "z": out += string(date_get_day_of_year(dat)-1); break;
        case "t": out += string(date_days_in_month(month)); break;
        case "L": out += string(date_leap_year(dat)); break;
        case "w": out += string(weekday); break;
        case "N": out += string(((weekday+6) mod 7)+1); break;
        case "W": out += string(week); break;
        case "c": out += date_format("o-m-dTH:i:s",dat); break;
        case "r": out += date_format("D, j M Y H:i:s -0000",dat); break;
        case "\": i += 1; c = string_char_at(str,i);
        default:  out += c; break;
        }
    }
    return out;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that `@param` is appropriated before a description?

Comment: Right you are, whooops

Comment: You may have posted a lot more than necessary, which is pretty unusual for SO :)  What environment/editor?

Comment: @NetMage When it comes to a specific regex issue I thought it best to post an entire example of what's in a sample file as that caught me out when trying to do this myself a few times (And yet someone still put in a close request for it being too broad). The functions are for Game Maker Studio but I can run the regex in pretty much anything, I was using a JetBrains IDE to try out solutions earlier. As this will only be run once to convert from the older style formatting to JSDocs I can just use what's needed at the time if someone gives me a specific solution for vim for instance.

Answer (score 0):

So using emacs I created a regex search and replace:

search for:

```
\(^[^/^J]+^J^J\)// +\(.+\)^J// +\(.+\)^J
```

and replace with:

```
\1// @description \2 \3^J
```

Note that each ^J is Ctrl-J in emacs.

Looking at the IDEA reference, I would suggest searching for:

```
(^[^/\n]+\n\n)// +(.+)\n// +(.+)\n
```

and replace with:

```
$1// @description $2 $3\n
```